# Jtextfield with autocomplete or Jsuggestfield java swing

Tags: java, json, swing, jtextfield

Which is better to use between jtextfield with autocomplete or jsuggestfield what i want to achieve here is i have a json file and from that file i want to select the names of all members in that json and when i type `A` in the field all the names that starts with letter will appear as dropdown and adding a letter will filter the list with names starting with `A` and what ever letter is typed

FYI:

found the jsuggestion [here](http://www.rakudave.ch/jsuggestfield) but i only understand little from there because it is not really explained there

Comment: How much time (and will power) do you have to create your own?

Comment: The API is out of date or using bad mechanisms (`Vector` is no longer encouraged)

Comment: little to no experience in java swing application development..but i need to make one with autocomplete data from autocomplete comes from json file

Comment: Take a look at the [`AutoComplete` decorates from the SwingX API](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases)

Comment: im looking at your link and there is no autocomplete here sorry

Comment: Yes, there is, but it's contained within [binaries](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/download/releases/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar) and you can read the [javadocs](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/download/releases/swingx-all-1.6.4-javadoc.jar) for more details

Comment: i see i thought it will be tutorial i downloaded the jars thanks for idea i will search on how to implement them

Comment: It sounds you can fulfil your requirement with a `JComboBox` as well

Comment: @Robin Jcombox and what sir?do i need to use other stuff for that please explain further